# Displex terminal path issue

Tags: command-line, indicator, applet

I last installed displex from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/displex/files/

Since then I've been having a small problem with my terminal. Each time I open my terminal while displex is running my default location is set to "/usr/share/indicator-displex$`instead of`~$`.

I don't have any problem running my commands but I would like to have it going to `~$` without having to do `cd ~` every time.

Comment: You should check if in your shell startup files (`/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`) there is some `cd` command or something weird that you can relate to `displex`.

Comment: Did you do something to make DisPlex automatically run at login? If so, what?

Comment: Thanks fior the response. I found a way out, like you said I first looked in the profile files but nothng to find. Then I tought a bit further about your answer and looked in the "/usr/bin/indicator-displex" file and found a solution. The first command in the files is "cd /usr/share/indicator-displex" I put "# " in front of that command (so it doesn't get executed) and it solved my problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [enzotib](https://askubuntu.com/users/2647/enzotib), who pointed me in the right direction, I was able to solve my question myself.

1. Enter in terminal: `gksu gedit /usr/bin/indicator-displex`

   (You can use any text editor instead of `gedit`. If you choose to use a command-line editor, like `vi` or `nano`, use `sudo` instead of `gksu`.)
2. On the third line you wil see `cd /usr/share/indicator-displex`, change this to:

   ```
   # cd /usr/share/indicator-displex
   ```
3. Save the file, and you're done.